# Blazor Html Templating Engine - is there a way to do this?

Tags: .net, events, blazor, components

I am trying to create a Blazor Templating engine.  Basically - lets say there is an HTML string as follows:

```
    <div>
        <div>This is some text</div>
        <div>{Component}</div>
        <div>This is some more text</div>
    </div>
```

The HTML is dynamic and loaded from an API. Blazor will render this - and using string replacement/regex, in the place of the {Component} - it will render a specific Blazor component.

The main issue is being able to render the Component.

I have tried using the inbuilt HtmlRenderer, to render the required component as a string, but if it do this, any 'events' in the component (onclick, onchange) get lost.

I have tried using RenderFragment, but the same thing appears to happen.

My question: Is there a way to render a blazor component to a string, and retain, or atleast reattach any dynamic events within in?

I have scoured Stackoverflow etc, and can't find guidance on how blazor renders components and builts the inbuilt events...

Comment: Is your html xml-compliant?  You could load it into a XDocument and interpret that in a RenderTreeBuiilder.